# Changing GameObject Position with Unity and ARToolkit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gameobject, artoolkit

I'm building an Augmented Reality app with Unity and ARToolkit for Android.  I have multiple GameObjects on screen that are children of my marker.  Works well.  I then created a very simple script to move one of the objects and I attached the script to the game object.  It looks like:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 currentPos = transform.position;
    transform.position = new Vector3(currentPos.x + (.01f * xDirection * xSpeed), currentPos.y + (.01f * yDirection * ySpeed), currentPos.z);
}
```

The rest of the script does nothing other than alter the value of the direction and speed variables.  It works and goes in the directions that I expect, however the object shrinks in size visually.  Possible it's just lower on the z axis so it appears smaller, or possible scaling is getting affected.  I think it may be related to the movement of the phone up and down while looking at the marker.

I suppose I have to move GameObjects in a different manner than normal when using ARToolkit.  What's the proper way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've no connection with ARToolkit by try checking out their [Coordinate System](https://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/documentation/cs.htm)